# Java SSL truststore seems to be accessible without specifying password?

Tags: java, ssl, truststore

I have a file, ote.truststore, that I've set with a custom password using Keystore Explorer 5.1, and I'm using it for an API servlet running under Tomcat 7/Java 1.7. **What I can't understand is how the servlet is managing to open the file even though I've not specified the password anywhere in code, configuration or ssl.properties.**

I know that the servlet is opening the right file because I have javax.net.debug.all enabled, and I can see in the log the trusted CA certificate that it finds ("CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G3").

I verified that I can change the password to any random string, and the servlet still opens the truststore. I also verified that if I remove the file and restart the servlet, I get "trustStore is: No File Available, using empty keystore." in the log.

Is there something in the JKS format that says passwords don't apply to truststore files? That would seem odd to me. When I try to open the file in Keystore Explorer without specifying the correct password, it dutifully fails to decrypt.

Comment: Servlet does not access the keystore, it is the servlet container that does that. Check your servlet container config or runtime arguments.

Comment: @Downvoter, care to explain what's wrong with the question?

Comment: @JunedAhsan Regardless of whether it's the servlet or the servlet container that accesses the truststore (not the keystore) can you think of an explanation of how it is working if the password has not been specified in any configuration file? I literally generated a random password, applied it to the truststore using Keystore Explorer (without changing any servlet/Tomcat config) and found that the servlet was still able to open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Password is not required to read a trust store. No private key is involved.

You still need password to modify a trust store. Also, when reading a trust store, *if* the password is provided, it can be used to verify the integrity of the trust store.

ref - http://bayou.io/release/0.9/javadoc/bayou/ssl/SslConf.html#trustStorePass-java.lang.String-