# Where is a CAcert's password used?

Tags: ssl, certificate, certificate-authority, java

I am working with a vendor's appliance, and they use the default Java `cacert` for adding certs for allowing self-signed certs. When working on this process, I noticed that the cacert uses the default password `changeit`

For increased security, I would like to change the `cacert` password.  Instructions are online. However, I am worried that once I change the password applications using `cacert` will stop functioning correctly.

I realize I don't really understand how Java is accessing `cacert`.

- Does it need the `cacert` password?
- Does anything need the `cacert` password?
- Or do you only need the `cacert` password when adding or removing certs?

Comment: Don't change the system `cacerts` file (it's not called `cacert`) at all. Instead, make a copy of it and make all the changes you want to the copy. The password provides tamper detection for the file, but you can still use it without a password if you don't care to verify the contents.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732484/java-ssl-truststore-seems-to-be-accessible-without-specifying-password?rq=3  (I was expecting the password to do more when writing this question.   Check out this question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, it's `cacerts` with an 's' at the end, not `cacert`. The password is only needed to modify the file, and that included adding or removing certificates. You don't need the password to use this file, though if you do supply a password it will be used to verify the integrity of the file.

Java by default uses `cacerts` when verifying certificate chains and by default it does not use a password. Even though the JDK ships the `cacerts` file protected with the password `changeit` the Java runtime does not assume this. You can change the default behavior in a few ways, the simplest of which is to set the Java system property `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` to the password. There is also a Java system property `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` that can be used to point to a file you want to use in place of `cacerts`. Using these tools you can, all optionally and independently:

1. change the password on the system wide `cacerts` file.
2. Tell Java to use the password to verify the integrity of the file.
3. Tell Java to use a completely different file in place of `cacerts`.

There is one obvious caveat that needs to be mentioned nevertheless. You say this is a vendor's appliance. That means the Java environment may have already been customized. Perhaps there is already code there that assumes the `cacerts` password is `changeit`. You did ask if *anything* uses the `cacerts` password.

The above is really just a summary, the full story is documented in the [JSSE Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html). One particularly [relevant section](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html#GUID-32CF3420-56E8-4BC5-8D3B-1F6B4692A290) to your question I'll reproduce here:

> You can either implement this interface directly yourself or obtain
> one from a provider-based TrustManagerFactory (such as that supplied
> by the SunJSSE provider). You could also implement your own interface
> that delegates to a factory-generated trust manager. For example, you
> might do this to filter the resulting trust decisions and query an
> end-user through a graphical user interface.
>
> If a null KeyStore parameter is passed to the SunJSSE PKIX or SunX509
> TrustManagerFactory, then the factory uses the following process to
> try to find trust material:
>
> 1. If the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` property is defined, then the TrustManagerFactory attempts to find a file using the file name
>    specified by that system property, and uses that file for the KeyStore
>    parameter. If the `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` system property
>    is also defined, then its value is used to check the integrity of the
>    data in the truststore before opening it. If the
>    `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` property is defined but the specified file
>    does not exist, then a default TrustManager using an empty keystore is
>    created.
> 2. If the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` system property was not specified, then:
>    - if the file `java-home/lib/security/jssecacerts` exists, that file is used;
>    - if the file `java-home/lib/security/cacerts` exists, that file is used;
>    - if neither of these files exists, then the TLS cipher suite is anonymous, does not perform any authentication, and thus does not
>    need a truststore.
>
> To know more about what java-home refers to, see Terms and
> Definitions.
>
> The factory looks for a file specified via the
> `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` Security Property or for the `jssecacerts`
> file before checking for a `cacerts` file. Therefore, you can provide
> a JSSE-specific set of trusted root certificates separate from ones
> that might be present in `cacerts` for code-signing purposes.

Comment: One of the main points here, that I missed at first, is that the password is not used to just access the cacerts when applications use SSL.

Answer (score 2):

`$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts` is the Java installation's default truststore.

A truststore is the same as a keystore but applied differently at runtime. It is advisable to create your own keystore and truststore files if you need them and tell the JVM where to find at startup.

You can assign passwords to Java Keystore (jks files), you can assign passwords to certificates/keys stored inside the keystore, you can even do both at the same time.

The default password for the java truststore is `changeit`, and if you take it seriously you are even asked to change it. When starting some java application you can specify the location and password of the keystore, and usually for applications requiring a key you can also specify the alias and password used to fetch the key from the keystore.

See also

- [Keystore vs Truststore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341566/4222206)
- [how to change the keystore or the key's password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889238/keystore-change-passwords)
- [how to start an application with a changed keystore/password](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29585_01/PlatformServices.61x/security/src/csec_ssl_jsp_start_server.html)
- Just as an example for an application using a keystore [how to edit the Tomcat configuration file](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File) and [Tomcat TLS configuration options](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_Certificate)

Comment: Hey, I am not sure if you really got my question.  I am working on getting it reopened.  Maybe is wasn't clear.  I am asking about the cacert password.  The cacert is the Certificate Authority repository.  I am asking about the password for cert.

Comment: Certificate Authority repository -> Truststore

Comment: The whole question was about how and when the password was used.

Comment: Did you read 'how to start an application with a changed keystore/password'?

Comment: I had not read that, however, that does seem relevant.